# Gson deserialize lowercase JSON to camel-case Class object

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON with all the fields set lower-case. The problem is: my POJO object has attributes set as camel-case, and when I try to deserialize with Gson.fromJson my camel-case attributes are not set.

Example JSON:

```
[
    {
        "idpojo": 1,
        "namepojo": "test"
    }
]
```

POJO Class:

```
public class Pojo {

    private Integer idPojo;
    private String namePojo;

    //constructors, getters and setters

}
```

Deserialization code:

```
List<T> objects = new ArrayList<>();
// At this point I only have an variable with a reference to a classe. Let's assume it is in fact a reference to Pojo class
Class VARIABLE_WITH_REFERENCE_TO_A_CLASS = Pojo.class;
Class pojoReference = VARIABLE_WITH_REFERENCE_TO_A_CLASS;
String json = EXAMPLE_JSON_HERE;
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
int len = jsonArray.length();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    objects.add((T) new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray.get(i).toString(), pojoReference)));
}
```

The reason I am deserializing the JSON to a list of a generic class instead of a list of Pojo class is because at this point of my code I don't know what Class I should create my collection.

This code works fine. The problem is: the camel-case attributes from the Pojo class are not set after the deserialization.

What I have tried so far has been using the @SerializedName annotation on the fields, and also creating custom deserializers, but neither do the trick for me, because I really don't want/can write specific code for deserialization of objects.

**Question:**

Using generic, how can I deserialize a JSON object with lower-case attributes to a Java class (like Pojo.class) with camel-case attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem using Jackson instead of Gson for deserialization.

Jackson must be version 2.5 or superior, also one must configure the mapper to accept caseinsensitive attributes.

New working code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);

List<T> objects = new ArrayList<>();
// At this point I only have an variable with a reference to a classe. Let's assume it is in fact a reference to Pojo class
Class VARIABLE_WITH_REFERENCE_TO_A_CLASS = Pojo.class;
Class pojoReference = VARIABLE_WITH_REFERENCE_TO_A_CLASS;
String json = EXAMPLE_JSON_HERE;
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
int len = jsonArray.length();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    objects.add(mapper.readValue(new JSONObject(json).toString(), pojoReference));
}
```

Thanks to everyone for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of `fromJson()` method says that the type of object you are deserializing the JSON into cannot be generic. You can specify a type and use the @SerializedName attribute like you mentioned to overcome your problem of mismatched casing, but only if you know the type of object you are creating from the JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Tyler, but I said, this is not a option for me.